# How to show a new UIViewController without a NavigationController

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have an active view, and upon request of the user, I would like to load a different viewController from NIB.
That viewController has a `cancel` button upon which the user goes back to the previous view.
I don't have a UINavigationBar to handle the segue, but I do need the new ViewController to take place when needed.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `presentViewController:animated:completion:` to present the new `viewController` and `removeFromParentViewController` to remove it.